# How many customers made a purchase for the first time at STORE 1 per month?

Tags: sql

Hey guys I'm having trouble solving an exercise of SQL:
I can't seem to understand how can I write a query that answers the question in the title based on a purchase database.
I tried selecting distinct values per month, but the same customer can make a purchase in different months, so they would end up being duplicated.

```
SELECT 
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.order_date) AS year,
 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.order_date) AS month,
 COUNT(DISTINCT o.customerID) AS total_customers
FROM `store1.Orders` AS o
JOIN `store1.Customers` AS c
ON o.customerID = c.customerID
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY month ASC
```

Columns of store1.Orders:

- orderID
- order_date
- purchase_status
- revenue
- customerID

Columns of store1.Customers:

- customerID
- Name
- e-mail

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach the problem from user, not from order.

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as new_customers,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM custs.first_order_date) AS year,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM custs.first_order_date) AS month
FROM
 (SELECT
    MIN(o.order_date) as first_order_date,
    o.customerID
    FROM store1.Orders o
    GROUP BY c.customer_ID) custs
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY month ASC
```

There may be typos or syntax errors in the query, I didn't test it. But you'll get approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, I'm sorry, I'm kind of a beginner

Comment: nope, I'm understanding now hold a sec

Comment: thank you so much @ex4 !
I wasn't aware of the min/max functions, but I totally understand the use here: listing the minimum value of purchase date for each customerID shows me the first purchase of each customerID, is this right?

Comment: Yes, in the subquery result is customerid and their first (smallest) order date. Then you make your query against that resultset